# scrapy where is the scrapyd.confg file

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, windows-7, scrapy

I am reading this page

http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html

and It states that the scrapyd.conf should be existing in

```
c:\scrapyd\scrapyd.conf
```

However, I don't have scrapyd folder in my c driver. But I have **TWO** folders it in these paths:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scrapyd
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scrapyd-1.0.1-py2.7.egg-info
```

Non of them has the scrapyd.conf file.

I need to change this value

```
poll_interval = 20
```

Where can I find that file please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The docs don't state that `scrapyd.conf` should be existing in `c:\scrapyd\scrapyd.conf`. They say:

> Scrapyd searches for configuration files in the following locations, and parses them in order with the latest one taking more priority

So just create file `scrapyd.conf` with this content:

```
[scrapyd]
poll_interval = 20
```

And put this file in one of the mentioned locations (for example in project directory).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already did that and It works. I mean, I can deploy my project and I can see the items and the logs, but the interval is not working. I mean the spider works for just one time, I need it to work every `20` seconds. why please?

Comment: Could you check my question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109713/scrapy-spider-sends-spider-close-signal-before-it-closes